# how can I use WCF trace, and group multiple traces from different threads in the same activity?

Tags: wcf, trace

I trace web requests to my REST service. The requests come on various threads from distinct users but I want all recess that are for the method getSomeData() to be grouped under the same activity in the TraceViewer tool so I don't end up with 100 activities all containing one trace (As you can see below in second and third activity). 
[image]

If I use code such as

```
ts.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 1, "http://api.foursquare for {0}, {1}, nrOp={2}", lat, lng, valOp1.Count());
ts.Flush();
```

in my getSomeData method I will get 100 different activities, all containing 1 trace, if invoked by 100 users which is very frustrating to read. I would prefer all traces to be included in an acuity (preferably if I could give it a name such as getSomeDataTraces)

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you could try setting the [CorrelationManager.ActivityId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.correlationmanager.activityid.aspx) before tracing. If you set it to the same value every time it may just end up as one activity in the trace viewer.

Answer (score 0):

May be late for the reply, but the following link really helped me a lot:

http://dotnetcodecentral.com/Post/311/wcf/trace-log-messages-from-end-to-end-using-wcf-and-a-client

The crucial part is "propagating" the ActivityID across tiers (through configuration).  I am still experimenting the same approach for WCF REST/Data Services (OData), but with no luck (yet!).